# How to interleave 3 float vectors into an array with AVX intrinsics C++

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I have 3 `__m256` vectors x, y, z filled with 8 elements of data each (single precision floats),
and I'd like to store them interleaved into memory `[x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, ...]`.

What are the relevant and useful operations to use to store them into a (possibly unaligned) array or `std::vector`?

The brute force way is obviously terrible unless the compiler turns this into some vector shuffles:

```
#include "immintrin.h"
#include <vector>

// actually the results of computation, so typically already live in regs
__m256 x = _mm256_set_ps(7.0f, 6.0f, 5.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
__m256 y = _mm256_set_ps(7.1f, 6.1f, 5.1f, 4.1f, 3.1f, 2.1f, 1.1f, 0.1f);
__m256 z = _mm256_set_ps(7.2f, 6.2f, 5.2f, 4.2f, 3.2f, 2.2f, 1.2f, 0.2f);

std::vector<float> result;
result.resize(24);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    result[i * 3] = x[i];
    result[i * 3 + 1] = y[i];
    result[i * 3 + 2] = z[i];
} // result = {0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 1.0f, 1.1f, 1.2f, etc..}
```

Comment: Are they actually in *memory* to start with, or are those `__m256` "arrays" (actually vectors) the result of a computation that just completed so they're already going to be in registers?

Comment: Related Intel article: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/3d-vector-normalization-using-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx.html (how to transpose 3x8 matrices)

Comment: The arrays will be the result of computation that just completed, so they will be in registers. Sorry for the ambiguity! Thanks for the Intel article, it solves my problem!

Comment: @chtz: That's using only AVX1, so it seems rob's AVX2 answer is significantly better for Skylake and similar CPUs.  (Like twice the throughput, including stores, if the store buffer can absorb any extra cost of the stores being unaligned)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
typedef __m256 f256;
typedef __m256i i256;

#define set8i _mm256_setr_epi32

inline f256 permute8f(const f256 a, const i256 choice) {
   return _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(a, choice); 
}

template<bool c0, bool c1, bool c2, bool c3, bool c4, bool c5, bool c6, bool c7>
inline f256 select8f(const f256 tr, const f256 fr)
  { return _mm256_blend_ps(fr, tr, (c7 << 7) | (c6 << 6) | (c5 << 5) | (c4 << 4) | (c3 << 3) | (c2 << 2) | (c1 << 1) | c0); }

void vec3_soa_to_aos(f256& A, f256& B, f256& C,
         const f256 x, const f256 y, const f256 z)
{
  // indices so we can permute into something sane. 
  const i256 PX = set8i(0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5);
  const i256 PY = set8i(5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2);
  const i256 PZ = set8i(2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7);

  // re-arrange so we can select correct elements.
  const f256 X = permute8f(x, PX);  // 0.0f  3.0f  6.0f  1.0f  4.0f  7.0f  2.0f  5.0f
  const f256 Y = permute8f(y, PY);  // 5.1f  0.1f  3.1f  6.1f  1.1f  4.1f  7.1f  2.1f
  const f256 Z = permute8f(z, PZ);  // 2.2f  5.2f  0.2f  3.2f  6.2f  1.2f  4.2f  7.2f 
  
  // perform our two stage selection
  const f256 A0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(X, Y);  // 0.0f  0.1f  whatever  1.0f  1.1f  whatever  2.0f  2.1f
  const f256 B0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(Z, X);  // 2.2f  3.0f  whatever  3.2f  4.0f  whatever  4.2f  5.0f
  const f256 C0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(Y, Z);  // 5.1f  5.2f  whatever  6.1f  6.2f  whatever  7.1f  7.2f
  A = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(Z, A0);  // 0.0f  0.1f  0.2f  1.0f  1.1f  1.2f  2.0f  2.1f
  B = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(Y, B0);  // 2.2f  3.0f  3.1f  3.2f  4.0f  4.1f  4.2f  5.0f
  C = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(X, C0);  // 5.1f  5.2f  6.0f  6.1f  6.2f  7.0f  7.1f  7.2f 
}

// for completeness.... 
inline void vec3_aos_to_soa(
  const f256 A, const f256 B, const f256 C, 
  f256& x, f256& y, f256& z)
{
  const f256 X0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(A, B);
  const f256 Y0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(C, A);
  const f256 Z0 = select8f<1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0>(B, C);

  const f256 X = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(C, X0);
  const f256 Y = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(B, Y0);
  const f256 Z = select8f<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0>(A, Z0);

  const i256 PX = set8i(0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5);
  const i256 PY = set8i(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 0, 3, 6);
  const i256 PZ = set8i(2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7);

  // rearrange and output
  x = permute8f(X, PX);
  y = permute8f(Y, PY);
  z = permute8f(Z, PZ);
}

__m256 x = _mm256_set_ps(7.0f, 6.0f, 5.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
__m256 y = _mm256_set_ps(7.1f, 6.1f, 5.1f, 4.1f, 3.1f, 2.1f, 1.1f, 0.1f);
__m256 z = _mm256_set_ps(7.2f, 6.2f, 5.2f, 4.2f, 3.2f, 2.2f, 1.2f, 0.2f);

vec3_soa_to_aos(x, y, z, x, y, z);


std::vector<float> result;
result.resize(24);
_mm256_storeu_ps(result.data(), x);
_mm256_storeu_ps(result.data() + 8, y);
_mm256_storeu_ps(result.data() + 16, z);
```

Comment: 3 shuffles and 6 blends is pretty good on modern Intel (like Skylake), where immediate blends of 32-bit element-size or wider (like your `vblendps`) can run on any of the
 3 vector ALU ports.  https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/3d-vector-normalization-using-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx.html presents and AVX1-only algorithm that uses 128-bit stores, using 6x `vshufps` ymm and 3x 128-bit `vmovups` stores, 3x `vextractf128 [mem], ymm, 1` (2 uops not micro-fused on Skylake, but only for the store ports).  So 1 per 6 clocks.

Comment: vs. yours with a throughput including the 3x 256-bit stores of 3 shuffles, 6 blends, 3 stores = 12 uops, but evenly distributed across back-end ports for a best-case throughput of 1 per 3 clocks on Skylake / Ice Lake, keeping all thee vector ALU ports saturated, and the store-data port saturated on SKL.